# jquery ajax form submit request with first click is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

Greeting to all,

I'm developing an app with monorail + jquery, and i've found a problem with the ajax working from jquery.

I've a form that submits it-self into a div container, usually works fine, but every once in a while the form doesn't submits on the first click, and i need to give a second click to get it working

I've checked it out with Firebug and the request remains processing as is shown in this image: 
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c6f500d617.jpg

If i press the submit button again, then the request is processed.

The code i'm using is pretty much this:

```
    $('.formSteps').submit(function () { // catch the form's submit event
    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
        type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
        url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
        success: function (response) { // on success..
            $('#service_plan_wizard_container').html(response); // update the DIV
        }
    });
    return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
});
```

As you may guess, there is a div called service_plan_wizard_container and this happens with every form with the class formSteps.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your code:

```
context: this,
```

right above

```
data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
```

and

```
var that = this;
```

below the submit trigger, then use "that" instead of (this)

Comment: i'm not sure to be following you,  you mean this:
    $('.formSteps').submit(function () { 
        var that = this;
        $.ajax({ 
            context: this,
            data: that.serialize(), 
            type: that.attr('method'), 
            url: that.attr('action'), 
            success: function (response) { 
                $('#service_plan_wizard_container').html(response); 
            }
        });
        return false; 
    });
I did that and the submit happens but it doesn't load on the div.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue just now. I was hoping that this post would help me out, but nothing I found (which was little) would help.

I have figured out why though.

Insert this somewhere in the ajax request:

```
async: false,
```

This completely fixed the thing in one second.

By the way, I realized if you put this into your ajax request as well, you can actually get an error message on that first click:

```
error: function(er, err, error){
      alert(error);
},
```

The reason I was getting no response from the server is not because it wasn't firing, it's because it was returning an error instead of a "success" response.

Also, when debugging this, I greatly recommend using FireBug for Firefox and you can monitor any Ajax requests in the (Net->XHR) tab. Very helpful!